# use exit(0) to close an app in iphone 4 instead of send it in background mode

Tags: iphone, ios4

I've noticed that pressing the iphone button using SDK 4 sends the application in background.
Since I'm dealing with login and other problems I find better closing the app instead of sending it in background status. So I would put an `exit(0);` statement inside `(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`.

Is it a correct approach or is against Apple guidelines?

Comment: Don't do that. Just don't. What problems do you have with the background mode? Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: the main concern was that my app is enabled to open pdf file from Mail or Safari. But if I start my app then send it in background, if i open the app via Safari or Mail it just don't open the file because it doesn't call (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually i found the answer by myself: I can set in the info.plst the option "Application does not run in background" to control this behavior instead of using exit(0) command

Comment: There you go. Also, I don't know if it's a concern for you or not, but an app that calls `exit(0)` violates the Human Interface Guidelines rather seriously and runs a substantial risk of not being allowed into the app store.