# Using exit(0); in iphone app

Tags: iphone

Will the application get rejected if we use exit(0); in our application?

Comment: I can't even muster a sigh at this point.

Comment: You're not supposed to be able to quit an app by anything but the home button !

Answer (score 3):

Calling `exit(0)` will send the application to the background, but such action should only be initiated by the user. From Technical Q&A QA1561 [How do I programmatically quit my iPhone application?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html).

> There is no API provided for
>   gracefully terminating an iPhone
>   application. Under the iPhone OS, the
>   user presses the Home button to close
>   applications. Should your application
>   have conditions in which it cannot
>   provide its intended function, the
>   recommended approach is to display an
>   alert for the user that indicates the
>   nature of the problem and possible
>   actions the user could take - turning
>   on WiFi, enabling Location Services,
>   etc. **Allow the user to terminate the
>   application at their own discretion.**

Answer (score 1):

One of my application got rejected due to this. So Don't dare to try it. Its out of HIG.

Comment: Can we use exit(0)in applicationWillTerminate() to ensure releasing and web connections?

Comment: i think you can't use it anywhere

Comment: You could, perhaps, but it would not add anything useful in that respect. Normal termination is almost equivalent to exit (0).

Answer (score 1):

Please search before you ask questions..See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288461/use-exit0-to-close-an-app-in-iphone-4-instead-of-send-it-in-background-mode) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541051/exit-iphone-application), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342210/is-it-ok-to-use-exit0-in-applicationdidenterbackgrounduiapplication-applic) ...All from stackoverflow..Also look at apple's [QA](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html) where apple strongly discourage quiting app by program..