# Terminate xcode app due to time out

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an app in Xcode which handles sensitive data. I would like to terminate the app / exit forcefully if there is inactivity for 5 mins. Can someone please tell me how to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7590-touch-event-countdown-timer.html) for a tutorial on how to make a timer. Every action that the user takes, reset the timer. When the 5 minutes are up, you can use `exit(0)`.

However, this method of programatically closing your app is [discouraged by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html), so use it at your own discretion.

**Edit:** In order to stop the timer, you need to store a pointer to the timer that you create, and then call:

```
[pointerToTimer invalidate];
pointerToTimer  = nil;
```

**Edit 2:** An alternative to using `exit(0)` would be to make a almost blank screen except for some text that states:

> You have been inactive for too long. Please exit and restart this application.

Make this screen appear once the timer gets to 5 minutes. Therefore, the user can't do anything on the app but look at the screen, or exit the app.

Comment: Will this make apple decline the app if I submit it to the app store?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5788836/612266), it's very possible that your app will get rejected. One second, I'll think up a better option.

Comment: I added an alternative possibility.

Comment: That is a fantastic idea, after the timer expires I should load a new view with no navigation possibilities which will make the user exit and reload the app! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It should ideally, let me try and get back!!

Comment: Some users will have a problem quitting the app completely. Better explain how to do it in your "info view".

Comment: Yes, do you mean I should specify that user should press the "Home Button" to exit the app?

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing an app to submit to the app store, you can't (according to the guidelines).  See details in this note: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#qa/qa1561/_index.html

If you don't care about the store or interface guidelines, it suggests that exit() is available.

Comment: Is there no way to time out the app legally? I want to submit the app to the app store.

Comment: I only know what is in the Tech. Note I quoted: "Allow the user to terminate the application at their own discretion.". You can disallow any other function and explain why the app isn't working as it normally would.

Comment: Yes, that is what I exactly did. Thanks Phillip!!